# convert character to data frame or matrix with fixed number of columns

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I am trying to extract the values from a website. The extracted values look like this.

```
"3000       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1"                        
"4600       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1"                        
"4800       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1"                        
"5000       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1                     300"
"5200       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1"                        
"5400       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1"                        
"5600       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1                      10"
"5800       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1                       1"
"6000       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1                    5461"
"6200       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1                      54"
"6400       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1                    2009"
"6600       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1                     124"
"6800       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1    UNCH                     '1                     410"
"7000       ----      ----      ----      ----        '1     -'1                     '2                   10704"
"7200       ----      ----        '2A     ----        '2     -'1                     '3                    9927"
"7400       ----      ----      ----      ----        '3    UNCH                     '3                    7869"
"7600       ----      ----      ----      ----        '4    UNCH                     '4          30       13596"
"7800       ----      ----      ----      ----        '5     -'1                     '6         109       16030"
"8000         '7        '7        '7        '7        '7     -'1         467        1'0         731       26912"
"8200        1'4       1'4       1'3      ----       1'2     -'2         119        1'4         222       11030"
"8400        2'2       2'2       2'0       2'0       1'7     -'4         426        2'3         172       15743"
"8600        3'1       3'3       2'7       3'0A      3'0     -'4          66        3'4         330       18964"
```

There are some rows with less columns values. I want to create a data frame of 11 columns and the values which are blank should remain blank. When I try to split the values based on space the rows with less column values gets overlapped and repeated. Please find the code which I have tried.

```
  cc=gsub("\\s+"," ",df)
  cc=data.frame(cc)
  cc = data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(cc),' ',fixed=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't try using `read.table()` ?

Comment: Why are you `gsub`bing out the space?  Seems like it might make more sense to `strsplit` on `\\s+`

Comment: i am splitting it in the later step. I want to replace all the blank spaces with a single space then split the values based on the single space

Comment: I extract the values from webpage using readlines and take the part which i want. So I will not be able to use read table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update, original question has changed.

It looks like your data is fixed-width format. You can use `?read.fwf`, though its use depends somewhat on how reliable your data source is. If the place you are getting your data from had a specification as to how the data would always be formatted (e.g. "11 columns of width 10 characters each"), that would be helpful.

```
# pad out each line to the same length
maxlen <- max(sapply(df, nchar)) # it's 110 for your data, it seems
df <- sprintf(paste0("%-", maxlen, "s"), df)
read.fwf(textConnection(df),
         widths=c(4, 11, 10, 10, 11,  9,  8, 12, 11, 12, 12))
```

The widths I've picked are appropriate to the data you provided; you will have to determine sensible values for yourself based on what you expect.

---

You could just use indexing to put NAs in the empty spots, e.g. `(1:9)[1:11]` will select the first 9 elements (being `1:9`) and then put two `NA` on the end to pad it out to 11 elements long.

```
# assuming df is such that df[1] is the first line, df[2] is the second etc
tmp <- strsplit(df, '\\s+')
ncols <- max(sapply(tmp, length)) # could do max(lengths(tmp)) if you have a new
                                  # enough R. Or if you already know there are
                                  # at most 9 columns just set it to 9 directly
cc <- do.call('rbind', lapply(tmp, '[', i=seq_len(ncols)))
cc <- data.frame(cc)
```

Comment: tried this it does not seem to work according to my requirement. Thanks for your help. if the first line has some spaces in between values moves to the previous columns

Comment: there are situations when i need to put NA in the columns which are in between also.

Comment: Well, your original problem and reproducible example did not reflect this, so I couldn't mind-read it. I'll have a look at your updated problem.

Comment: The separator between the columns - is it a tab, or is it spaces? are there always at least 4 spaces between the columns?

Comment: ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/pub/settle/stlags they are just spaces.. I am trying to pul values from this website.

Comment: are there always at least 4 spaces between the columns?  And do you know in advance that there are only ever 11 columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83935/discussion-between-arun-raja-and-mathematical-coffee).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the constant distances in your columns, each column covers the characters start:end. If there are missing columns at the end, NA will be filled to the columns.
The variable "line" contains one single line of the extracted file.

```
start <- c(1,6,17, 27,37,47,57,65,77,88,100)
end   <- c(5,16,26,36,46,56,64,76,87,99,110)

columns <- list()    
for(j in 1:length(start)){
    if(start[j] <= nchar(line)){
        columns[[j]] <- substr(line, start[j],end[j])
    }
    else{
        y[[j]] <- NA
    }    
}
```